# check max characters in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, max, character

I have textboxes where i only want signed a max number of characters in. an then I'll hear how i could check it easily in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `MaxLength` property of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `MaxLength Property` of the textbox as you want.

E.g: if you want [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) as 10. give MaxLength - 10

Answer (score 0):

[TextBox.MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) maybe?

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively you could add a [jQuery plugin](http://www.anon-design.se/demo/maxlength-with-jquery)

Comment: No need to add client-side plugins for standard properties